# SQL query with multiple joins and I am adding more

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have this working SQL query:

```
SELECT * from ( SELECT distinct ts.users_user_id
          from subjects s LEFT JOIN teachers_subjects ts
          ON s.subject_ID = ts.subject_id
          JOIN users_teachers ut
          ON ut.user_id = ts.users_user_id
          LEFT JOIN stations st
          ON st.station_id = ut.station_id
          LEFT JOIN majors mj
          ON mj.major_id = ut.major_id
          ".$where." ) qualified
          JOIN users u ON qualified.users_user_id = u.user_id
          JOIN users_teachers ut ON qualified.users_user_id = ut.user_id
          JOIN teachers_subjects ts2 ON qualified.users_user_id = ts2.users_user_id
          JOIN subjects s2 ON ts2.subject_id = s2.subject_id
          LEFT JOIN stations st ON ut.station_id = st.station_id"
```

It was made to a) be able to match against certain search criteria and b) allow me to output multiple subject_ids per result, as each result represents a teacher who teaches more than one subject, which is why there are two joins of the same columns.

I now have to add to this mess with an additional two joins.

```
SELECT * from ( SELECT distinct ts.users_user_id
          from subjects s LEFT JOIN teachers_subjects ts
          ON s.subject_ID = ts.subject_id
          JOIN users_teachers ut
          ON ut.user_id = ts.users_user_id
          LEFT JOIN stations st
          ON st.station_id = ut.station_id
          LEFT JOIN majors mj
          ON mj.major_id = ut.major_id

              LEFT JOIN lessons l
              ON l.teacher_id = ut.user_id
              LEFT JOIN ratings r
              ON r.lesson_id = l.lesson_id    

          ".$where." ) qualified
          JOIN users u ON qualified.users_user_id = u.user_id
          JOIN users_teachers ut ON qualified.users_user_id = ut.user_id
          JOIN teachers_subjects ts2 ON qualified.users_user_id = ts2.users_user_id
          JOIN subjects s2 ON ts2.subject_id = s2.subject_id

               LEFT JOIN lessons l2 ON l.teacher_id = qualified.users_user_id
               LEFT JOIN ratings r2 ON r2.lesson_id = l2.lesson_id

          LEFT JOIN stations st ON ut.station_id = st.station_id"
```

Unfortunately, I am not getting the desired output. a) the correct lesson ids are not being outputted (only a couple of the many that should be) and b) the number of items in an array deriving from the lessons table has n times as many members as it should, where n = number of subjects for that teacher. so there is a lot of redundancy and a lot of empty array slots

Any help is much appreciated

Lessons table structure:

```
    CREATE TABLE `lessons` (
   `lesson_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `lesson_date` date NOT NULL,
   `time_began` time NOT NULL,
   `time_ended` time NOT NULL,
   `duration` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'minutes',
   `total_fee` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `student_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `teacher_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `request_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `pay_rate` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `subject_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `student_reject` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `student_reject_comment` text,
   `lesson_notes` text,
   PRIMARY KEY (`lesson_id`),
   KEY `student_id` (`student_id`),
   KEY `teacher_id` (`teacher_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=40 ;
```

Ratings table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `ratings` (
`lesson_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`like_dislike` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`review` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`lesson_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Desired output:

```
[rej] => Array
    (
        [avatar] => 122.JPG
        [email] => 
        [last_name] => kob
        [user_name] => rej1324558654
        [english_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => SAT                    
                [1] => math
            )

        [station_en_name] =>
        [country_prefix] => AR
        [pay] => 201
        [lesson_id] => Array
            (
                [0] => 11
                [1] => 12
                [2] => 13
                [3] => 14
            )

    )
```

The original output features quadruples of every subject names, not the right lesson ids, not and many blank slots in the lesson_id array

Comment: Is this really the right join condition:  `l.teacher_id = ts.users_user_id`?

Comment: no, you're right. i've changed it, still same errors though.

Comment: @compguy24 could you provide a table structure and the desired result to you question. Even better would be two provide it with some sample data and create a SQLFiddle at www.sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: @Mr.Radical minus the SQL Fiddle, I've put up the tables and the arrays I'd like

Comment: To start: `l.teacher_id = qualified.users_user_id` change into `l2.teacher_id = qualified.users_user_id`

Comment: @compguy24 I have to honest it looks very complicated. Your question would be a lot easier if you add the remaining tables and give some sample data. Furthermore,  the desired result in the form of a table would also be nice.

Answer (score 0):

this probably isn't what you want to hear, but I'd really strongly recommend breaking this query into multiple bite-sized, testable chunks. It'll add some I/O, but you can control that with VIEWS or CTEs, depending on your environment. And while it might not be best for a production run, having the control totals will let you identify where the problem is coming from in the first place.

If you decide to do this, I'd start with the following

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT subject_ID) FROM subjects; 
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT subject_id) FROM teachers_subjects;
SELECT count(*)
   FROM  subjects as s
   INNER JOIN teachers_subjects as ts
      ON s.subject_ID = ts.subject_id ;
```

And then move down the list and test all of the joins.

It's a lot of work to test all of this, but it'll probably pay off, both in terms of fixing whatever the problem is now, as well as troubleshooting whatever issues might come up later. If this is a live data environment, you can reasonable expect something to go wrong eventually... some data gets loaded incorrectly or whatever. Having the control totals written in advance will let you zoom in later to fix whatever problems might come along, not just this one that you're starting with